# I'm making a counter that tracks pressing the space bar. But I have a problem. When I pinch the space, the numbers are added anyway

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
canvas=Canvas(root,width=400,height=300,bg='white')


count = 0


def clicked(e):
    global count
    count += 1
    Click.configure(text=count)

Click = Label(root, text = '0', font = 'Arial 35')
Click.pack()


root.bind("<space>", clicked)
root.mainloop()
```

When pressed, the counter does not stop stopping

Comment: What does "pinch[ing] the space" mean? Whaat do you mean "does not stop stopping"?

Comment: By "pinching", do you mean "pressing and holding"?

Answer (score 0):

I understood that the problem was that the count incremented when I held down the space key. If that's a problem, I think you can bind to the key release event.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
canvas=Canvas(root,width=400,height=300,bg='white')

count = 0

def clicked(e):
    global count
    count += 1
    Click.configure(text=count)

Click = Label(root, text = '0', font = 'Arial 35')
Click.pack()

root.bind("<KeyRelease-space>", clicked)
root.mainloop()
```